# Getting data from JavaScript charts

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, amcharts

On this [link](https://pricespy.co.uk/product.php?pu=2180326#) you'll a chart for the price history of an Apple iPhone, my goal is to be able to access this data somehow, I've looked at the source code and there is no mention of any prices but on the web there is the ability to hover over a data point and get the price for a given date, meaning this data has to be available.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please include _all_ relevant information and code _in the question itself_. Remember, _links rot_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is stored within the chart instances' `dataProvider` array. Since their code is minified, you'll have to use the global `AmCharts.charts` array to get at their `dataProvider` arrays instead. Note that there are three charts on this page (the tiny sparkline chart in the Statistics tab is an AmCharts instance as well). The array is populated in order of creation in the page, so the first one is the sparkline, and the other two are the popularity and price history respectively.

Here's my console output from accessing the first item from the popularity history chart's dataProvider:

```
> AmCharts.charts[1].dataProvider[0]
Object {time: Mon Sep 16 2013 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time), value: 561756}
```

Alternatively, you can also just use your browser's web developer console and filter out the AJAX/XHR calls to find the raw data as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the code and play a little with the charts you will see:

```html
<path cs="100,100" d="M-23.5,203.5 L-9.5,203.5 L-16.5,203.5 L-7.5,203.5 L-7.5,190.5 L6.5,190.5 L-0.5,190.5 L8.5,190.5 L8.5,148.5 L22.5,148.5 L15.5,148.5 L23.5,148.5 L23.5,162.5 L37.5,162.5 L30.5,162.5 L39.5,162.5 L39.5,176.5 L53.5,176.5 L46.5,176.5 L55.5,176.5 L55.5,162.5 L69.5,162.5 L62.5,162.5 L70.5,162.5 L70.5,176.5 L84.5,176.5 L77.5,176.5 L86.5,176.5 L86.5,148.5 L100.5,148.5 L93.5,148.5 L101.5,148.5 L101.5,162.5 L115.5,162.5 L108.5,162.5 L117.5,162.5 L117.5,176.5 L131.5,176.5 L124.5,176.5 L133.5,176.5 L133.5,176.5 L147.5,176.5 L140.5,176.5 L148.5,176.5 L148.5,148.5 L162.5,148.5 L155.5,148.5 L164.5,148.5 L164.5,162.5 L178.5,162.5 L171.5,162.5 L180.5,162.5 L180.5,162.5 L194.5,162.5 L187.5,162.5 L195.5,162.5 L195.5,176.5 L209.5,176.5 L202.5,176.5 L211.5,176.5 L211.5,176.5 L225.5,176.5 L218.5,176.5 L226.5,176.5 L226.5,176.5 L240.5,176.5 L233.5,176.5 L242.5,176.5 L242.5,148.5 L256.5,148.5 L249.5,148.5 L258.5,148.5 L258.5,103.5 L272.5,103.5 L265.5,103.5 L273.5,103.5 L273.5,54.5 L287.5,54.5 L280.5,54.5 L289.5,54.5 L289.5,71.5 L303.5,71.5 L296.5,71.5 L305.5,71.5 L305.5,71.5 L319.5,71.5 L312.5,71.5 L320.5,71.5 L320.5,87.5 L334.5,87.5 L327.5,87.5 L336.5,87.5 L336.5,87.5 L350.5,87.5 L343.5,87.5 L352.5,87.5 L352.5,19.5 L366.5,19.5 L359.5,19.5 L367.5,19.5 L367.5,19.5 L381.5,19.5 L374.5,19.5 L367.5,19.5 L367.5,19.5 L381.5,19.5 M0,0 L0,0" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="1" stroke="#FFD400"></path>
```

Where #FFD400 is the color of the chart. Maybe datas are "d" attribute but I don't know enough to understand the format.

I hope it will help.

Comment: That's way off. The `d` attribute contains the commands used to draw the shape. It has nothing to do with the data. You should read up on the documentation for `path` in [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths).

Comment: Thank you! Really usefull!!